# C# Async Select

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following working code:

```
var failures = _validators
    .Select(v => v.Validate(request))
    .SelectMany(result => result.Errors)
    .Where(f => f != null)
    .ToList();
```

The `Validate` method returns a `ValidationResult` object.

I want to change the `Validate` method to `ValidateAsync`, then I use `async/await` inside the `Select`. Now it does not return `IEnumerable<ValidationResult>`, but instead `IEnumerable<Task<ValidationResult>>` and the `SelectMany` call does not work anymore.

So I changed the code like this:

```
var failures = _validators
    .Select(async v => await v.ValidateAsync(request))
    .SelectMany(result => result.Result.Errors)
    .Where(f => f != null)
    .ToList();
```

I'm using the `Result` property of the `Task` object to access the `ValidationResult` object.

I remember reading something a long time ago about using that `Task.Result` could lead to possible deadlocks. Is this solution good or is there a better one?

Comment: The `ValidateAsync` signature is  `Task<ValidationResult> ValidateAsync(object instance, CancellationToken cancellation = default);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use this extension:

```
public static async Task<TResult[]> SelectAsync<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, Task<TResult>> selector)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    }

    if (selector == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selector));
    }

    return await Task.WhenAll(source.Select(selector));
}

var temp = await _validators
    .SelectAsync(v => v.ValidateAsync(request));

var result = temp.SelectMany(result => result.Errors)
    .Where(f => f != null)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: It does not work too, your method is returning a `Task<ValidationResult[]>` which does not have a `SelectMany` method.

Comment: @RBasniak probably you forgot await?